# PHP Page is posting multiple times occasionally

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a registration form which posts data to save.php. But occasionally the data is getting posted multiple times.

Below is my code for save.php

```
<?php
session_start();
//save registration details in my table

include('connect_database.php');
include('my_functions.php');

$_SESSION['newUser'] = '0'; // new user

//POSTED DATA--------------------------
$t_email = $_POST['email'];
$t_psw = $_POST['psw'];
$t_first_name = addslashes($_POST['first_name']);
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $t_last_name = addslashes($_POST['last_name']);
$t_mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$_SESSION['licNum'] = $t_lic_no = $_POST['lic_no'];
$t_dob = $_POST['dob'];
$t_abn = $_POST['abn'];
$tx_expiry = $_POST['tx_expiry'];
$drv_for = $_POST['driven_for'];
$lng_drv = $_POST['long_driven'];

//referred by
$ref_drLic = $_POST['ref_driLic'];
$ref_drName = $_POST['ref_driName'];

$t_dr_front = get_image('dr_front',$_POST['last_name'].'_dr_front');
$t_dr_bck = get_image('dr_bck',$_POST['last_name'].'_dr_bck');

//if tx required-------
if($_SESSION['ce_cr_tx'] == 1){
    $t_tx_front = get_image('tx_front',$_POST['last_name'].'_tx_front');
    $t_tx_bck = get_image('tx_bck',$_POST['last_name'].'_tx_bck');
}
else{
    $t_tx_front = "";
    $t_tx_bck = "";
}

//store data in logfile
$nwtxt = "Email is - ".$_POST['email'].". Mobile no - ".$_POST['mobile'];
writeFile($nwtxt);

//---------------------------------------
//query to save data in my table 
$ad_sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (email, password, firstname, lastname, mobile, licence, drfront, drbck, txfront, txbck, cnfrm, dob, abnf, texpiry, drifor, driven, reLic, reNname)
    VALUES('".$t_email."','".$t_psw."','".$t_first_name."','".$t_last_name."','".$t_mobile."','".$t_lic_no."','".$t_dr_front."','".$t_dr_bck."','".$t_tx_front."','".$t_tx_bck."','0','".$t_dob."','".$t_abn."','".$tx_expiry."','".$drv_for."','".$lng_drv."','".$ref_drLic."','".$ref_drName."')";

if(!empty($t_email)){
    if($conn->query($ad_sql) == true){
        //echo'Success';
        $lst_id = $conn->insert_id;
        $_SESSION['ls_id'] = $lst_id;
        $_SESSION['s_email'] = $t_email;
        $_SESSION['s_code'] = mt_rand(11111,99999);

        //email code to user--------------------------
        $subjct = "Email Verification Code";
        $usr_msg = "Hi ".$_POST['first_name']." ".$_POST['last_name'].",<br><br>
                    A new account has been requested at 'Portal'
                    using your email address.<br><br>

                    To confirm your new account, please enter this code in the web page:<br>
                    <h3>".$_SESSION['s_code']."</h3><br><br>

                    If you need help, please call us<br><br>

                    Thank you,
                    Administrator";
        sendEmail($t_email, $usr_msg, $subjct); //sends and email
        writeFile('Code is :'.$_SESSION['s_code']); // write a log in file
        //--------------------------------------------      
        //redirect to verify email page----------------------
        header("location: verifyEmail.php");
        exit();


    }
    else{
        echo'Error creating account-  '.$conn->error.'. Please try again.';
        $gbck = "cr=".$_SESSION['ce_cr_id']."&crs=".$_SESSION['ce_cr_nm']."&tx=".$_SESSION['ce_cr_tx']."&erms=Error creating account. Please try again";
        header('location: Enroll.php?'.$gbck);
        exit();
    }
}
else{
    echo'Error creating account. Please try again.';
    $gbck = "cr=".$_SESSION['ce_cr_id']."&crs=".$_SESSION['ce_cr_nm']."&tx=".$_SESSION['ce_cr_tx']."&erms= EMPTY data. Error creating account. Please try again";
    header('location: Enroll.php?'.$gbck);
    exit();
}

?>
```

I checked my code multiple times but couldn't find anything that is triggering it. When someone registers, the page keeps loading for sometime and I receive multiple entries in database and user receives multiple verification emails.

Is something wrong in my code?

Comment: Check your webserver access log to see if the form is being submitted multiple times. Then check the submission code, not the script it posts to.

Comment: If someone presses the refresh button or back button your form will resubmit the form data because you take no precautions to prevent it

Comment: @JohnConde I was on call with the user. He clicked on the submit button just once and didn't click on the back button.

Comment: @Barmar, I checked my IIS server log. The page was loaded 4 times. First two times, it returned 500 error and the other two times the page loaded successfully and I received 2 registrations. User just clicked once on the register button and the page kept on loading until he was redirected to the next page.

Comment: You should check the PHP error log to see why it's getting a 500 error.

Comment: @Barmar I checked php error logs. Couldn't find anything related to 500 error. Just found this - PHP Notice:  session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(C:\Windows\temp) failed: No error (0) in c:\website on line 2

Comment: That sounds like there's a problem with your PHP configuration, the session files can't be found.

Comment: @Barmar But there are session files in C:\Windows\temp

Answer (score 0):

The code itself looks fine, but i get the growing suspicion that it might be a config issue or whats happening before this executes. If your looking for a patchwork fix i would probably put a condition near your `if(!empty($t_email))` that checks if the sql table row already exists dont execute, which would rectify the fact that multiple requests are coming in.

Comment: I have a suspicion on header() function. Do you think it might be the reason for page reload?

Comment: Its kind of hard to tell but i get the growing suspicion that save.php is being called multiple times outside the file which would explain the multiple entries. you could call ``session_destroy()``` after writefile, if multiple entries still occur it would lead to that hypothesis being true